# Two jar files in quarkus target directory

Tags: java, jar, quarkus

Whenever I build my quarkus project using `quarkus build` command it generates two jar files in the target directory of my program. One of them is at the root of the target directory and has the name of my project. The other one is situated inside the `quarkus-app` folder and has the name `quarkus-run.jar`

However whenever I run the jar file that has the name of my project it gives me the following error:
`Error: Main method not found in class com.humblepenguin.Main, please define the main method as: public static void main(String[] args) or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application`

However when I run the other jar file (the quarkus-run.jar one) everything works perfectly.

Here is my Main.java file:
`
package com.humblepenguin;

```
import io.quarkus.picocli.runtime.annotations.TopCommand;

import picocli.CommandLine;

import com.humblepenguin.Server;
import com.humblepenguin.Client;

@TopCommand
@CommandLine.Command(mixinStandardHelpOptions = true, subcommands = { StartServer.class,         StartClient.class })
public class Main {

 }

 @CommandLine.Command(name = "server", description = "Start the server on port 8080")
 class StartServer implements Runnable {

  @Override
  public void run() {
    System.out.println("Starting server");
    Server server = new Server(8080);
    server.start();
  }
}

 @CommandLine.Command(name = "client", description = "Start a client instance to connect to the server")
 class StartClient implements Runnable {

  @Override
  public void run() {
    Client client = new Client();
    client.run();
  }
}
```

`

I tried looking for some explanation online however there are very limited tutorials and guides on Quarkus.